# My website is unavailable after trying to upgrade from Umbraco 7.15.6 to Umbraco 8.1.0

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

I tried to upgrade my website from 7.15.6 to 8.1.0

I used FileZilla to copy /bin and /Umbraco to my host. Then, I edited the web.config as explained here: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Upgrading/migrating-to-v8

The installation process didn't start and my website is unavailable.

When I tried to rollback to 7.15.6, I now get the following error: Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The type 'Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication' is ambiguous: it could come from assembly 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\umbraco.DLL' or from assembly 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin\Umbraco.Web.DLL'. Please specify the assembly explicitly in the type name.

Source Error:

Line 1: <%@ Application Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %> Line 2:

Source File: /global.asax Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4261.0

I copied again /bin and /Umbraco to my host (of 7.15.6), as well as the config and App_Plugins folders

How can I bring my website back???

Thakns.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove umbraco.dll for a start. In fact, all Umbraco DLL's starting with a lowercase 'u' shouldn't be there.

Comment: Hi, thanks. So actually I just copied again the /umbraco and /bin directory of 7.15.6 - so can I assume that it has only the U7's dll's?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, sorry :-/ If you're not using Nuget (and even if you are), upgrading from v7 to v8 is not done simply by copying files. https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/setup/upgrading/migrating-to-v8 says "it will not be possible to do a direct upgrade from Umbraco 7 to Umbraco 8". Instead, it might be easier to create a fresh v8 installation, point it to your (backed up) v7 database and then copy over view files and such. It's not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do an upgrade from 7 to 8 by copying files as [Umbraco 8 contains a lot of breaking changes and a lot of legacy code has been cleaned up compared to Umbraco 7.](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/getting-started/setup/upgrading/migrating-to-v8#migrating-content-to-umbraco-8) Due to this, it is not possible to do a direct upgrade from Umbraco 7 to Umbraco 8.

Instead you can migrate your content from your Umbraco 7 site into your Umbraco 8 site after you fresh up a new Umbraco 8 website - again this is not an upgrade!

PS 1: Please use Nuget to install&upgrade your packages.

PS 2: I wrote a blog about [my Umbraco V8 "upgrade" from V7 experience](https://nurhak-kaya.blogspot.com/2020/07/umbraco-v8-upgrade-from-v7-developer.html) a while ago, please take a look. I'm adding the conclusion bit from my blog here, hope it helps.

- It seems to be Umbraco v8 upgrade from v7 is not really an upgrade, but literally creating a new v8 project, doing the data migration, moving the custom code&settings, and making sure all is good again. You should know that for big projects, this is a lot of work and you need to make sure this is really what you want/need to do.
- When creating new projects, definitely v8 should be your choice as it is the main focus of Umbraco, and it is [the greatest version so far](https://umbraco.com/blog/umbraco-7-to-umbraco-8-a-developer-s-perspective/).
- For v7 projects, I wouldn't recommend you to do a v8 upgrade, unless you have got real good reasons and time(and money to spend for this). Umbraco will continue to support v7 which is great news for all v7 projects.
- For data migration, writing your own data migration code could be a good option, similar to what [Paul Seal did](https://codeshare.co.uk/blog/how-i-migrated-my-umbraco-v7-site-to-v8-part-1-media/).